# angular 6 and node.js Server on linux

Tags: node.js, angular, raspberry-pi

I created a angular6 webpage with anuglar cli. this page communicate with a node.js Server. 
I had created it on windows and it works fine...
I start angular with a

```
ng serve
```

nd my server with

```
node serve.js
```

so... now i'd like to do the same on a Linuxsystem (raspberry pi) and make it global

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

and

```
node api.js
```

but angular won't speak to node serve...

Comment: have you looked into angular.json? you can configure serve there.

Comment: my ng serve is running fine... .i see my page in browser on 192.168.1.20/4200

Comment: ok. ng serve is creating a lite-server automatically. what do you need the other server for?

Comment: with the node server i connect to mySql database.I see the page in the browser.  But the console say...GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MOcTRvq net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED